# Iteratively generating animations - android

Tags: java, android, animation, iteration

I am trying to make a TapTapRevenge-esque game and I'm having trouble generating the note animations. I have a note class:

```
class Note {
    int hitTime;
    int y;
    int pos;
    int iniX;
    Bitmap img;
}
```

I make my notes from a `2D array` such as this one:

```
int[][] rawNotes = {{0, 1000},{1,1000},{2,1100},{0,1250},{1,1500}};
```

with the following method,

```
public void makeNotes(int[][] in) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int sW = metrics.widthPixels;
    for(int i=0;i<in.length;i++) {
        notes[i] = new Note();
        notes[i].hitTime = in[i][1];
        Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ball);
        notes[i].img = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(temp, sW/10, sW/10, false);
        switch (in[i][0]) {
            case 0 :
                notes[i].iniX = sW/3 - sW/20;
                break;
            case 1:
                notes[i].iniX = sW/2 - sW/20;
                break;
            case 2:
                notes[i].iniX = (2 * sW/3) - sW/20;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

and I update their positions with the following lines of the `onDraw` method in my `SurfaceView` class,

```
    for (Note note : notes) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgr,0,0,null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(note.img,note.iniX,note.y,null);
        note.y = (1500 + (songTime - note.hitTime));
    }
```

Where background is just my background image.

For some reason, only the second item in my `array` of notes (`{1, 1000}` in this case) gets displayed. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong here.

Thanks